# .htaccess encode %{QUERY_STRING}

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a complete url (including QUERY_STRING) to a `index.php?url=[url]&query=[query]`. The following rule works for that:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&query=%{QUERY_STRING} [B]`. The `B` flag ensures encoding for the `$1` part, but doesn't encode the `%{QUERY_STRING}`. How can I encode that too?

Example:

`http://www.website.com/test&test.php?arg1=val1&arg2=val2` rewrites to `Array('url' => 'test&test.php','query' => 'arg1=val1', 'arg2' => 'val2')`, where `Array('url' => 'test&test.php','query' => 'arg1=val1&arg2=val2')` is expected.

Comment: Why don't you take the `query string` from PHP and use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to create your array?

Answer (score 1):

First off, you could leave the existing query string untouched by using the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [B,QSA,L]
```

As a second idea, you could bring the query string down to the rule as a first step, then capture it to cause the proper encoding by the `B` flag. I haven't tested it, so try these two options::

Option 1

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1&query=%1 [B,L]
```

Option 2

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(?!index)(.*) %1URL$1 [B]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)URL(.*) index.php?url=$1&query=$2 [B,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*
RewriteRule .+ index.php?url=$0&query=%0 [B,L]
```

I used .+ in the rule to avoid double rewrites caused by mod_dir (DirectorySlash and DirectoryIndex)